# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when concatenating variable and HTML script element src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, callback, concatenation

Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error in chrome where I concatenate the "url" variable to the script element src attribute. In the console the error starts at the second concatenation operator and goes to the end of the closing script tag in the following line.

`var script = '<script src='+url+'></script>'`

The script variable is defined inside a callback function where I am dynamically setting the script element's src url based on the button that is clicked. The error is occuring on page load before the the event that triggers the callback is fired. So when the error occurs the function has not been called and "url" includes undefined variables.

```
function update(){
   var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
   var parameters = getParameters(clicked);
   var defaultField = parameters[0];
   var defaultUnits = parameters[1];
   var url= '"https://....jsembed=true&timeControl=true&fieldControl=true&defaultField='+defaultField+'&defaultUnits='+defaultUnits+'"';
   var script = '<script src='+url+'></script>';
   var container = document.getElementById("container")
   container.innerHTML=script;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the browser sees `</script>` it interprets this as the closing tag of your script block. In this case this means terminating the script block in the middle of a string which makes the syntax invalid.
It doesn't matter if it's inside a JS string, the HTML parser has absolute precedence.

You can solve this quite easily by changing that line into this:

```
var script = '<script src='+url+'></s'+'cript>';
```

Comment: Thank ou for the explanation! This solves the problem and works perfectly but @thedarkone's solution of using a backslash to escape the forward slash in the closing script tag also solved it and they answered first.

Comment: @Drazah That explanation of the issue is inaccurate though. A forward slash is **not** an escape character in strings.

Comment: The description of the forward slash as an escape character is not accurate. But the solution of adding the backslash to escape the forward slash in the closing script tag solves the problem equally as well as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
var script = `<script src=${url}</script>`
```

I get the feeling that the combination of strings and the `'` and `"` may have screwed something up. This is a *template literal*, where you can use variables in strings. However, you must use the backtick.

Comment: that didn't work, now the whole string is underlined as an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions actually to your code.
One is like UghThatGuyAgain just mentioned use a template string and make it

```
var script = `<script src=${url}><\/script>`;
```

The other is how you are doing it.

```
var script = '<script src='+url+'><\/script>';
```

The issue with your solution is basically the **/** part. It basically is an escape character, so you have to handle it differently.

Comment: escaping the forward slash in the closing script tag solved it.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer. This solution did solve the problem but @Mikael Lennholm's solution also solves the problem and descibes the root of the problem more accurately.

Comment: No problem, he has a lot more experience. I just learned something new also.